# How to Convert to XTS in r?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert this data to XTS format.
The idea is to be able to use this in the `highfrequency` package.

How do I do this?

```r
data= read.csv("", header=T)
options(digits.secs = 6)

as.POSIXlt(data, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

> Error in as.POSIXlt.default(data, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") : 
>     do not know how to convert 'data' to class “POSIXlt”`

[image]

Comment: It's `as.POSIXlt(data$datetime, ...)`. And `as.POSIXct` is better.

Comment: Can you update your post with `dput(head(data))` ?